# How can i return the max of a sum by each team?

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have a lot of teams and i want to know the maximum of sum total of each team.

This's my query :

```
SELECT campaign_id, 
       campaign_identifier, 
       team, 
       campaign_name, 
       Month(time) AS month, 
       Sum (total) AS Total 
FROM   campaign 
WHERE  Year(time) = Year(Now()) 
       AND Month(time) = 12 
GROUP  BY campaign_identi, 
          team
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If am not wrong this is what you need

```
select team,max(Total)
from
(
SELECT team, 
       Sum (total) AS Total 
FROM   campaign 
WHERE  Year(time) = Year(Now()) 
       AND Month(time) = 12 
GROUP  BY campaign_identi, 
          team 
) A
Group by team
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT MAX(Total) AS max_sum_total
    FROM (
        SELECT ... -- your query
         ) AS x;
```

You did not ask for it, but you probably want to say which team had the max?  Then you need [*groupwise max*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i want to return a max of sum of each team not which team had the max

Comment: Doesn't your query do that?

Comment: The OP's current query returns `SUM(Total)` per team and campaign, and the OP seems to want the MAX(SUM(...)) per team.