# Union Query format in mysql

Tags: mysql, join, union

I am training in MySQL.
I have database called ships. My goal is => For each class, define the number of ships of this class that were sunk in battles. 
Result set: class, number of sunked ships.
Here are the tables from which I wanna get the result:
[image]

I tried to resolve my problem in this way:

```
SELECT classes.class, COUNT(outcomes.ship) as sunks
FROM classes LEFT JOIN outcomes ON classes.class=outcomes.ship
WHERE outcomes.result='sunk'
UNION
SELECT ships.class, COUNT(outcomes.ship) as sunks
                FROM ships
                LEFT JOIN outcomes ON ships.name=outcomes.ship
                WHERE outcomes.result='sunk'
```

The result set of my query is just: Bismark and Kogo classes but other classes were gone.

But it was not exactly what I wanted to get.
I want to get all classes - even with zero outcomes.result.

What am I going to do to make it works properly?
Here is the table script just in case: [ships](https://www.sendspace.com/file/3ekel2)

Comment: The `WHERE outcomes.result='sunk'` nullifies the `LEFT` "effect" of the `LEFT JOIN outcomes` because it can never be true if the row does not exist (and WHERE is evaluated *after* JOIN). Either move the condition to the ON clause (as `ON classes.class=outcomes.ship AND outcomes.result='sunk'` - that was the condition is evaluated *during* the join, not *after*) or add an `OR outcomes.result IS NULL` to the WHERE. The UNION itself does not look like a bad idea to me, but it might happen that you get two rows for the same class, one originating in `ships` and the other in `classes`.

Comment: At first I tried to add `ON classes.class=outcomes.ship AND outcomes.result='sunk'` then `WHERE outcomes.result='sunk' OR outcomes.result IS NULL` but it did not take proper effect. The result is the same - just Bismark and Kongo.

Comment: Please consider re-posting your data samples as text. That way it will be easier to import them as tables for whoever would like to help you. To keep the tabular arrangement as in your screenshot, use the Code Sample formatting functionality (`Ctrl+K` on a selected fragment).

Comment: Andriy M, I have corrected my question and  add link with sql script for creation of  tables.

Comment: Related problem: [How can i return the max of a sum by each team?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/124193/30273)

Comment: @fuser ah, I missed one more thing - you are aggregating, but you forgot the `GROUP BY` clause, so each query of the union returns just one row counting all items together.. I will show that in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem is that you "override the LEFT join by using the WHERE clause referencing that table, so no "NULL" row can show in the results.

Second problem is that you are using an aggregate (`count()`) but you forgot to add a proper GROUP BY.

Fixing these the query looks like this:

```
SELECT class, count(ship) as sunks
FROM (
  ( 
   SELECT classes.class, outcomes.ship
   FROM classes
   LEFT JOIN outcomes ON classes.class=outcomes.ship AND outcomes.result='sunk'
  )
  UNION
  (
   SELECT ships.class, outcomes.ship
   FROM ships
   LEFT JOIN outcomes ON ships.name=outcomes.ship AND outcomes.result='sunk'
  )
) AS tmp
GROUP BY class
```

There is a fiddle based on your script to see it in action http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4840f6/8

Comment: thanks a lot, jkavalik!!! It's a great solution but there is one problem: result query returns duplicate of kongo class. So I have 9 rows in output instead of  8 rows. I tried to use `DISTINCT` in your query but it didn't work too.

Comment: @fuser I wrote about that in my first comment. Check the updated answer (and the new fiddle link too).

Comment: pardon for my inattention! everything is clear now!

Answer (score 0):

First, it looks like your "Bismarck" is missing in the "ships" table, and thus has no class -- so you might wish to make sure your data is correct :)

Second, I'd approach that with a subselect:

```
SELECT class,count(result) AS sunk
  FROM (
    SELECT s.class,o.result
      FROM ships s LEFT JOIN outcomes o ON (s.name = o.ship)
     WHERE o.result = 'sunk'
  )
 GROUP BY class;
```

The "inner select" would list all sunken ships classes, the "outer select" does the maths ;)

Comment: In this query I'll get only one result and it will be just `kongo`class because of omitting `class` from classes table. Anyway, thanks for helping!

Comment: That's what I meant by "make sure your data is correct" ("complete" would have been better). But you've found a way around it at least :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this is:

```
select
c.class,
(select count(o.ship) from outcomes o
left join ships s on s.name = o.ship
where (c.class = o.ship or c.class = s.class)
and o.result = 'sunk') as sunks
from
classes c
```

In this way I'll get all classes with sunk-table column and zero results if the ship didn't sunk.